# Nodemailer is not able to send mail using aws on production server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodemailer

I am getting the problem while sending mails through nodemailer and AWS. Following are the my settings :

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", smtpTransport({
    host: 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    service: 'SES',
    port: 25,
    secure: true,
    debug: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'XXX',
        pass: 'XXX'
    }
}));
```

Mail sending code:

```
    transporter.sendMail({
       from: xxx@xxx.com,
       to: xxx@xxx.com,
       subject: 'XXX',
       html: 'XXX'
      }, function(error, response) {
         if(error){
            console.log(error);
         }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
         }
 });
```

I am getting following error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 25,
  stage: 'init' }
```

Here's what my transporter object look like when I printed it :

```
Transport {
  options: 
   SMTPTransport {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     options: 
      { host: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
        service: 'SES',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        debug: true,
        auth: [Object] },
     logger: { info: [Function], debug: [Function], error: [Function] },
     name: 'SMTP',
     version: '2.4.1[client:2.3.1]',
     maxConnections: 5,
     maxMessages: Infinity },
  transportType: 'SMTP',
  dkimOptions: false,
  transport: 
   SMTPTransport {
     options: 
      SMTPTransport {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        name: 'SMTP',
        version: '2.4.1[client:2.3.1]',
        maxConnections: 5,
        maxMessages: Infinity },
     pool: 
      SMTPConnectionPool {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        port: 25,
        host: 'localhost',
        options: [Object],
        _connectionsAvailable: [],
        _connectionsInUse: [Object],
        _messageQueue: [Object],
        _idgen: 2 } },
  version: '0.3.35',
  sendMail: [Function] }
```

As you can clearly see it is using different setting then defined by me.

I am unable to find the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to send mail through aws it is better to use `aws-sdk` module. usage is given below

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
module.exports = function (to, from, sub, body) {
  aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
    secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
    region: 'region'
  });

// load AWS SES
  var ses = new aws.SES({apiVersion: 'latest'});


// this sends the email
  ses.sendEmail({
        Source: from,
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: to
        },
        Message: {
          Subject: {
            Data: sub
          },
          Body: {
            Html: {
              Data: body
            }
          }
        }
      }
      , function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent:');
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
};
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @FastTurtle But is there a way to fix the above error without using "aws-sdk"?

Comment: if your using docker on AWS ECS review your network settings or configs of the VPC and if your using Task Definition review the network type you using , please try out first type Bridge  then review to or revert to AWSVPC type